# Hello everyone, I am working through a program and stuck on a challenge and cannot figure out why this will not work

Tags: javascript

Task: Use a for loop to iterate through the array and increase each number by two.

```
const increaseByTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

What is wrong with my code here?

```
for (let i = 0; i < increaseByTwo.length; i+=2){ 
  
}
```

Comment: You never actually change the array, plus you skip values.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```js
const increaseByTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var newArr = [];
increaseByTwo.forEach(e=>newArr.push(e+2))

console.log(newArr)
```